# Cannot specify direction of longitude and latitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Currently i have two textfields that hold the values of my longitude and latitude coordinates. Though for some reason if i enter N,S,E,W at the end of the coordinates to specify the direction, it seems to be disregarded and only takes the number values and intern takes me to the wrong location.

Heres what i have done so far.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
region.center.latitude = [self.myTextField.text floatValue];
region.center.longitude = [self.myTextField1.text floatValue];
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];


MapPin *ann = [[MapPin alloc] init];
ann.title = @"Test";
ann.subtitle = @"test";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapview addAnnotation:ann];

}
```

Comment: Does the text field have a formatter attached?  Perhaps one that just accepts numbers?

Comment: no it doesnt how would i attach a formatter?

Comment: In fact you need to use the delegate for formatting.

Comment: could you help me out with an example @trojanfoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you're trying to set are [CLLocationDegrees](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/c:@T@CLLocationDegrees). To specify latitudes south of the equator or longitudes west of Greenwich, use negative numbers. The [`floatVlaue` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/floatValue) you're using is just throwing away the letters you're typing at the end, as they're not recognised as part of a floating point value.

Comment: ok that helps but could you also give me an example of how i should use it correctly?